# I want uneven interval on y-axis using recharts

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I recently started working with recharts, problem is that i want uneven intervals on y-axis. reason being i have large values (mostly over 100) and the change in them is in points, so to make them visually understandable i want something like 1/3 of y-axis represent lets say 100, next 1/3 represent 100-101 (range between values differ). some example data would be like

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Page A', uv: 400.23},
  {name: 'Page B', uv: 400.09},
  {name: 'Page C', uv: 400.90},
  {name: 'Page D', uv: 400.90},
  {name: 'Page E', uv: 400.23},
  {name: 'Page F', uv: 400.33},
  {name: 'Page G', uv: 400.40},
];
```

thanks in advance

PS: name is on x-axis and uv is on y-axis